# php mail not working

Tags: php, email, centos, sendmail

this is my code:

```
if (mail('email@mail.com','New booking', $_REQUEST['message'])) {
echo"<p>Thanks for your booking!</p>";
} else {
echo"<p>Booking failed, please call us to book...</p>";
}
```

But it keeps showing booking failed. my server is centos vps.

/usr/local/lib/php.ini was like this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =
```

so i changed it to this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

this still doesn't work and now i am out of ideas. i rebooted my server after each edit of php.ini

Comment: sendmail puts it's errors in `/var/log/messages` do you find anything useful there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but directadmin had changed permissions of exim folders which caused it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a `From:` address in your call to `mail()`. This is required by most SMTP-Servers and `sendmail`.

Comment: changed it to if (mail('my@email.com','New booking', $_REQUEST['message'], 'From: other@email.com')) { but still nothing